# Best method for detecting input changes with QDataWidgetMapper

Tags: qt4.8

I'm using QDataWidgetMapper for editing data-base.
Does QDataWidgetMapper or any class (parent/mapped widgets/etc.) emit a signal, when any user-data in mapped widgets changes? At least, is it possible to check the changes by a method call manually?

I want the user to approve changes before submit and to display an icon on the form if something has changed.

It appears to me to be a very basic feature, but I can't find it.

Should I really connect each mapped widget and check the changes for each widget individually?

Comment: what do you need such a signal for? the model get's updated automatically by the mapper.

Comment: I want the user to approve changes and to display an icon on the form if something changed. (Will edit)

Comment: Is your problem that your edit events are not processed until the editor loses focus?  That is my current problem.  One solution I'm pondering is to subclass the mapper and have my `addMapping` function tie edit signals to the mapper's `commit` slot.

Answer (score 0):

you can put the submit strategy of your mapper to manual submit, add a save button to the gui, after user clicks save you can ask for verification. if ok call mapper submit.